# WCF IOperationBehavior doesn't work, multiple Operation Behavior

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, aop

As AOP implementation I have two classes which derived from `IOperationBehavior` like:

```
public class RemedyBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior
{
    .....
    public RemedyBehaviorAttribute(params PrimitiveActivity[] pi)
    {
        PermissionsToCheck = pi;
    }
    ...
}
```

and

```
public class AuthorityCheckAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior
{
    ....
    public AuthorityCheckAttribute(bool initiateAuthorities = false)
    {
        InitiateAuthorities = initiateAuthorities;
    }
    ....
}
```

when I want apply them over WCF implemented operation like:

```
[RemedyBehavior(PrimitiveActivity.Search)]
[AuthorityCheck(true)]
public FindStudies_DTO_OUT FindStudies(FindStudies_DTO_IN findStudies_DTO_IN)
{
....
}
```

in `BeforeCall` of `IParameterInspector` one of them be initiated like:

```
class RemedyParameterInspector : IParameterInspector
{
    public bool InitiateAuthorities { get; set; }

    public PrimitiveActivity[] Permissions { get; set; }
    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
    {
    }

    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        //Here one of them initiated , just the first one
        // the Permissions is null if AuthorityCheckAttribute was the first
        // the InitiateAuthorities is null if RemedyBehaviorAttribute was the first 
    }
}
```

just `RemedyBehavior` constructor called and initiated, if I change the order of them like :

```
[AuthorityCheck(true)]
[RemedyBehavior(PrimitiveActivity.Search)]
public FindStudies_DTO_OUT FindStudies(FindStudies_DTO_IN findStudies_DTO_IN)
{
....
}
```

in `BeforeCall` just the`AuthorityCheck` stuff initiated because it's ctor callled as **I mentioned in comment in code** .

so why the constructor of both of them won't called as WCF operation behavior ?

is there a way to do this or I should combine theme as one class?

Any further help would be truly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I implemented `ApplyClientBehavior` and  `ApplyDispatchBehavior` for `AuthorityCheckAttribute` like:

```
 public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription,
        ClientOperation clientOperation)
    {
        RemedyParameterInspector paramInspector = new RemedyParameterInspector
        {
            InitiateAuthorities = InitiateAuthorities
        };
        clientOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(paramInspector);
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription,
        DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        RemedyParameterInspector paramInspector = new RemedyParameterInspector
        {
            InitiateAuthorities = InitiateAuthorities
        };
        dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(paramInspector);
    }
```

and for `RemedyBehaviorAttribute` like:

```
 public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription,
        ClientOperation clientOperation)
    {
        RemedyParameterInspector paramInspector = new RemedyParameterInspector
        {
            Permissions = PermissionsToCheck,
            InitiateAuthorities = InitiateAuthorities
        };
        clientOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(paramInspector);
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription,
        DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        RemedyParameterInspector paramInspector = new RemedyParameterInspector
        {
            Permissions = PermissionsToCheck,
            InitiateAuthorities = InitiateAuthorities
        };
        dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(paramInspector);
    }
```